Does fetching the time in a loop generate secure random numbers?
Rust doesn't have a random number generator in the standard library, so I've been experimenting with creating my own random() function. One simple option would just be to hash the current time, but of course that's insecure if an attacker who's trying to guess a random number knows what time it was generated.
My idea is to get the current time in a loop, hashing each time — essentially benchmarking the hash function itself (in this example I'm using xorshift* but it could be anything).
Of course, this relies on the system having an accurate and precise clock. But if you could guarantee that, would this algorithm be a good way to generate a random password, for example? Or is there a way to somehow figure out the CPU speed?
use std::time::{SystemTime, UNIX_EPOCH};

// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift#xorshift*
fn hash(mut x: u64) -> u64 {
    x ^= x >> 12;
    x ^= x << 25;
    x ^= x >> 27;
    x.wrapping_mul(0x2545F4914F6CDD1D)
}

fn random() -> u64 {
    let mut random = 0;
    for _ in 0..100 {
        let now = SystemTime::now()
            .duration_since(UNIX_EPOCH).unwrap().as_nanos();
        random ^= hash(now as u64);
    }
    random
}

This implementation is fairly quick and can generate a few megabytes of randomness per second.

It's worth mentioning that there are standard recommendations for various Rust crates for things omitted by its standard library. See https://blessed.rs/crates .

@Mark Schultz-Wu I understand what you mean, but blessed.rs is an "unofficial guide" according to your own link so it shouldn't be treated as authoritative.

They implement standard cryptographic prgs that are roughly three orders of magnitude faster than what you suggest. I won't turn this into an answer because I'm not an expert on PRGs, but unless this is for fun I see no reason to use a slow implementation of a PRG that makes no claims of cryptographic security (xorshift) compared to a fast, pre-existing implementation of a standard cryptographic prg.

@MarkSchultz-Wu Yeah, this is just for fun. But my function isn't even a PRNG (at least in the normal sense) so I'm not sure whether it's comparable to the standard PRNGs you linked.

It doesn't have to be for 'fun'.  Chaotic in-determinism is a scientific 'thing', so can be leveraged for TRNGs. But garbage collected languages are much better at it.

In general time is a terrible way of generating random numbers.  If you took any random nanosecond since the beginning of the universe as the seed it wouldn't have nearly enough entropy (less < 79 bits) for a secure number.  Hashing doesn't make things any more random it just makes it slightly more work to brute force.

There's a pretty good example of the power of jitter entropy here. Generation is incredibly simple, yet measurement is harder but doable.

Answering my own question because I found something interesting after doing a bit more research. It turns out that this is called jitter entropy, and it's used to provide cryptographically secure randomness to the Linux kernel as a fallback if the machine has recently booted and doesn't have enough entropy just yet. The source for the try_to_generate_entropy() function is basically:
while (!crng_ready() && !signal_pending(current)) { // if the main entropy pool isn't ready
    if (!timer_pending(&stack->timer) && try_to_del_timer_sync(&stack->timer) >= 0) {
        // set up a timer
    }
    mix_pool_bytes(&stack->entropy, sizeof(stack->entropy)); // add entropy to the pool
    schedule(); // call the process scheduler - unpredictable runtime
    stack->entropy = random_get_entropy(); // read directly from the Time Stamp Counter (TSC)
}

This seems to be almost the same function that I implemented, with the main difference being that the scheduler is being run manually, whereas a user-space program can't control when it will be interrupted.
Further reading: https://www.chronox.de/jent/CPU-Jitter-NPTRNG-v2.2.0.pdf
